# Laravel - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in Laravel JQuery

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have this Laravel-5.8 controller function:

```
public function findLeaveCount(Request $request)
{
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;
    $employeeemptypeid              = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('employment_type_id')->where('id', $userId)->first()->employment_type_id;
    $leavetypeid                    = DB::table('hr_leave_types')->select('id')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('id',$request->id)->first()->id;
    $authorizedleavedays            = 0;
    $authorizedleavedays            = DB::table('hr_leave_type_details')->select('no_of_days')->where('leave_type_id', $leavetypeid)->where('employment_type_id',$employeeemptypeid)->first();

   $availableleavedays = 0;
   $availableleavedays              = DB::table('hr_leave_requests')->select(DB::raw("IFNULL(SUM(no_of_days),0) as no_of_days"))->where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->where('leave_type_id', $request->id)->whereYear('created_at', '=', date('Y'))->first();
    return response()->json([
        'authorizedleavedays' => $authorizedleavedays->no_of_days,
        'availableleavedays' => $availableleavedays->no_of_days,
    ]);        
}
```

route/web.php

```
Route::get('get/findLeaveCount','Service\ServiceLeaveRequestsController@findLeaveCount')->name('get.leavecounts.all');
```

view: create.blade

```
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Leave Type:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <select id="leave_type" class="form-control select2bs4" data-placeholder="Choose Leave Type" tabindex="1" name="leave_type_id" style="width: 100%;">
                    <option value="">Select Leave Type</option>
                    @if($leavetypes->count() > 0)
                        @foreach($leavetypes as $leavetype)
                            <option value="{{$leavetype->id}}">{{$leavetype->leave_type_name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
                </select>
            </div>
          </div> 
            <input type="hidden" id="available_leave_daysx" class="form-control" value="0" >
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Authorized Leave Days:</label>
                <input  id="authorized_leave_days" type="number" class="form-control" value="0" style="width: 100%;" disabled>
            </div>
          </div>    
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Available Leave Days:</label>
                <input  id="available_leave_days" type="number" class="form-control" value="0" style="width: 100%;" disabled>
            </div>
          </div>
```

When the

```
<select id="leave_type" class="form-control select2bs4" data-placeholder="Choose Leave Type" tabindex="1" name="leave_type_id" style="width: 100%;">>
```

is onchange, it should perform this function:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('change', '#leave_type', function() {
            var air_id =  $(this).val();

            var a = $(this).parent();

    //        console.log("Its Change !");

            var op = "";
            
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: '{{ route('get.leavecounts.all') }}',
                data: { 'id': air_id },
                dataType: 'json',      //return data will be json
                success: function(data) {

                    console.log(data.authorizedleavedays);
                    console.log(data.availableleavedays);
                     $('#authorized_leave_days').val(data.authorizedleavedays);
                     $('#available_leave_daysx').val(data.availableleavedays);
                     
                     let authorizedLeaveDays = $('#authorized_leave_days').val(data.authorizedleavedays);
                     let availableLeaveDays = $('#available_leave_daysx').val(data.availableleavedays);
                     
                     let sumAvailableDays = parseInt(authorizedLeaveDays) - parseInt(availableLeaveDays);
                     #available_leave_days = sumAvailableDays
                },
                error:function(){

                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

But I got this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

When I click on it, this line of code is highlighted:

> ## available_leave_days = sumAvailableDays;

How do I resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: Did you add `#` here `#available_leave_days` by mistake?

Comment: Its an id. I derived it from here  <input  id="authorized_leave_days"

Comment: `#available_leave_days` this is invalid js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#available_leave_days` this is invalid js, if you want to set the input value use this. replace the whole success function with this below

```js
success: function(data) {
$('#authorized_leave_days').val(data.authorizedleavedays);
$('#available_leave_daysx').val(data.availableleavedays);

let sumAvailableDays = parseInt(data.authorizedleavedays) - parseInt(data.availableleavedays);

$("#available_leave_days").val(sumAvailableDays);
}
```

Comment: When I did that adding  $("#available_leave_days").val(sumAvailableDays);   I got this new error:   The specified value "NaN" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

Comment: The result for console.log(sumAvailableDays) is NaN

Comment: @mikefolu I think I guessed what you want, check my updated answer.

Comment: .fn.init [input#authorized_leave_days.form-control]
0: input#authorized_leave_days.form-control
length: 1
__proto__: Object(0)      and   k.fn.init [input#available_leave_daysx.form-control]
0: input#available_leave_daysx.form-control
length: 1
__proto__: Object(0)